# Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?

Tags: android, drawable, android-resources

In the Android SDK documentation, all of the examples used with the @drawable/my_image xml syntax directly address images that are stored in the res/drawable directory in my project.

I am wondering if it is explicitly not okay to create a sub directory within the drawable directory.

For example, if I had the following directory layout:

```
res/drawable
-- sandwiches
  -- tunaOnRye.png
  -- hamAndSwiss.png
-- drinks
  -- coldOne.png
  -- hotTea.png
```

Could I reference the image of a tuna salad sandwich as @drawable/sandwiches/tunaOnRye

Or do I have to keep the hierarchy flat in the drawable directory.

Comment: Please note that capital letters are not allowed in the res directory.

Comment: You can only do this with Gradle:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19859379

Comment: Is it possible to have **SIBLING** directories to drawable, with the drawable functionality?  So, res/tanks/drawble-[hdpi .. etc] and so on?

Comment: It's 2021. Has this been solved yet?

Comment: @Leszek yeah iOS supports this pretty basic feature. Why hasn't the Android team figured it out?

Comment: It's 2022. Has this been solved yet?

Comment: Has anyone found any solution to this, I got around 400 different pictures I need to work with and there are different sizes like 128x128 and 256x256 and so on... I want to put them in their own corresponding directories. Thanks in advance

Comment: Its 2023, sigh.

Comment: Ok, I can comprehend... when Android started, two bitmaps in only one app was far too much for that memory, but it's 2024. HAL, can you read me?

Answer (score 593, accepted):

No, the resources mechanism doesn't support subfolders in the drawable directory, so yes - you need to keep that hierarchy flat.

The directory layout you showed would result in none of the images being available.

From my own experiments it seems that having a subfolder with any items in it, within the `res/drawable` folder, will cause the resource compiler to fail -- preventing the `R.java` file from being generated correctly.

Comment: As of Android 2.2, this doesn't cause a compiler error, but any subdirectories are ignored when generating the R class.  This really sucks, and makes it hard to manage larger projects. =/

Comment: Totally agree. They need to come up with a better solution supporting sub-folders. It can't be that hard.

Comment: Hopefully this will be resolved soon, i've got over 100 assets, and even then i coded some of them out. Total night mare trying to manage any marginally complex project.

Comment: This is the corresponding Issue in the Android issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2018

Comment: I'm shocked about that! I'm trying to build a game and I have lots of images. Looks like I'm going to have lots of hard times.

Comment: 100 assets... Try it with 16 thousand assets.

Comment: I just flattened a bunch of GIF's into animations... I am not a happy camper about the messy folder.

Comment: for a half year I developing application on android platform, this issue always make me working hard to manage resources.. -,-a

Comment: Just discovered this issue by trying it, assuming it would work. It doesn't ... not cool! Makes me want to write something handle it myself.

Comment: Now, according to the [article](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2018#c64) it appears that if you use the Gradle build system you **can** have sub directories. However, Google will **not** be implementing this for other build systems (e.g. Ant, etc.). Relevant Comment: "Marking this as released. This is largely possible in the Gradle build system as it exists today, and we won't be implementing this for other build systems"

Comment: now I know this I am going to name using underscores, it seems the only way. E.g. virtualfolder_image1.jpg

Comment: I have found that subfolders aren't really ignored.. they are parsed (well.. at least they are read to see what kind of resource is there), but they don't get packaged into the apk. Pre-gradle project I worked on had flavors defined inside the `res` directory, which caused clean builds to last over 10 minutes (yes, a lot of resources, but still..). When we moved those outside of `res` directory, it dropped down to 3 minutes (still not using Gradle).

Comment: There actually seems to be some action going on in a 'newer' Android issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37009920#comment9. Hope this gets solved soon. Been waiting for this for years.

Comment: 2022... we still don't have this simple feature.

Comment: @MartinCapodici idea is ok-ish. But it would still be looking at 1000 lines of drawables instead of 10. This is why I always feel Android Studio is MILES behind XCode.

Answer (score 165):

The workaround I'm using (and the one Android itself seems to favor) is to essentially substitute an underscore for a forward slash, so your structure would look something like this:

```
sandwich_tunaOnRye.png
sandwich_hamAndSwiss.png
drink_coldOne.png
drink_hotTea.png
```

The approach requires you to be meticulous in your naming and doesn't make it much easier to wrangle the files themselves (if you decided that drinks and sandwiches should really all be "`food`", you'd have to do a mass rename rather than simply moving them to the directory); but your programming logic's complexity doesn't suffer *too* badly compared to the folder structure equivalent.

This situation sucks indeed. Android is a mixed bag of wonderful and terrible design decisions. We can only hope for the latter portion to get weeded out with all due haste :)

Comment: Just a note that capital letters aren't allowed in the drawable folder. I get the error: "Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]"

Comment: +1 for "mixed bag of wonderful and terrible design decisions"

Comment: Hardly a workaround : rather "what you should do so as not to go completely mad". It's ludicrous to be limited to one directory.

Answer (score 45):

Actually, on Android Studio it is possible. You can have nested resources as shown [**here**](https://github.com/eskimoapps/ResourceNestingExample) :

[image]

There is also a plugin to group resources [**here**](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/folding-plugin).

I recommend to avoid this though.

Comment: Hi, @android developer! I've tried to add this into build.gradle file: 
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res {
                srcDir 'src/main/res/drawable/ic-toggle'
            }
        }
    }, but I've got "Uri is not registered" for xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android. What could be the case?

Comment: @AlexKost I actually tried this only once. I'm not experienced with it enough to help. Sorry.

Comment: @RahulMandaliya Even though it's possible, I suggest not to use it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Why not?

Comment: @JoshHansen It's messy.

Comment: If any of the two files from different folders have same name, you may get an error.

Comment: @MallikarjunM This I didn't know, but even by looking at it, it seems like a too large workaround. I do wish Google would have provided a nicer way of course.

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution, however, wenn I put my assets (layout-files or xml-drawables) into a separat folder I get the error message: "Can't determine type for tag {LinearLayout,....}" for any XML file I move there

Comment: @BenjaminMesing While I know this solution exists, I'm against using it because it seems like a big workaround.

Answer (score 38):

Yes - it does suck :) However you can use the assets folder and have sub directories in there and load images that way.

Comment: the problem is not only for drawable folder but also for layout folder :( My layout's folder contains more than 100 xml files, and it's hard for me to open the right xml layout in this.

Comment: Appart for other objections, resources may be easily localized but AFAIK there is no l10n in-built mechanism for assets.

Comment: @anticafe use "Go to resource" in your IDE (Eclipse: CTRL+SHIFT+R, IDEA/Android Studio: CTRL+SHIFT+N)

Answer (score 24):

Use assets folder.

sample code:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = this.getResources().getAssets().open("test/sample.png");
} catch (IOException e) {
    ;
}

image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Comment: The only issue with this method is that there is a LOT more homework involved with using bitmaps. Android's resource system does a much better job of memory management. Why would you rebuild a memory management system when Android already does it? Espeically if he has 100+ images, that's a lot of loading and releasing of bitmaps.

Comment: This is a real problem is you plan to localize your application, also if you have different resources for different screen densities, so it is not a solution, just a workaround valid for only some cases.

Comment: I need to give @Fran 's comment at least a thousand upvotes :)

Answer (score 22):

I've wrote an eclipse plugin which allows to create virtual subfolder by separating the file name with two underscores `__`. The project is in early stages, but don't worry it won't crash your IDE

more details can be found here, feel free to fork and send pull requests:

https://github.com/kirill578/Android-Sorted-Res-Folder

[image]

Comment: Nice! Any chance of porting this to Android Studio as well?

Comment: I'm currently not even using android studio, so I guess, we will have to wait for some experienced to port it.

Answer (score 9):

I like to use a simple script to flatten an organized directory structure provided by designers to something that can be used to generate an R file.

Run with current path in drawable-hdpi:

```
#! /bin/bash
DIRS=`find * -type d`
for dir in ${DIRS} ; do 
  for file in `ls ${dir}` ; do
    mv ${dir}/${file}  ${dir}_${file};
  done 
  rmdir ${dir};
done
```

Comment: Your script will not work if there is sub folders under folders. I think you need to replace all '/' with '_' in ${dir}.

Answer (score 9):

In android studio with gradle you can have multiple source directors which will allow you to separate resources. For example:

```
android {
    ....
    android.sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs = ['src/main/extraresdirnamed_sandwiches', 'src/main/res']
    }
    ....
}
```

However the names must not collide which means you will still need to have names such as sandwiches_tunaOnRye but you will be able to have a seperate section for all of your sandwiches.

This allows you to store your resources in different structures (useful for auto generated content such as actionbargenerator)

Answer (score 6):

One way to partially get around the problem is to use the API Level suffix.
I use res/layout-v1, res/layout-v2 etc to hold multiple sub projects in the same apk.
This mechanism can be used for all resource types.

Obviously, this can only be used if you are targeting API levels above the res/layout-v? you are using.

Also, watch out for the bug in Android 1.5 and 1.6.
[See Andoroid documentation about the API Level suffix](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: To whoever downgraded this answer: Can you explain why? This mechanism, although not pretty, works well for me.

Comment: This is what I do as well and it works good enough. I have a bunch of small images that I don't want to expand out, so I keep them in their own folder.

Comment: Works well for me. And it is pretty for me. I am trying to add version 2 logic into my app. so v2 is good.

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround for this situation: you can create a `resVector` (for example) folder on the same level as default `res` folder. There you can add any `drawable-xxx` resource folders there:

```
resVector
-drawable
-layout
-color
```

After that all you need is to add

```
sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/resVector'
    }
```

into your `build.gradle` file (inside `android {  }`).

Comment: Sadly they're merge together in the project panel in Android Studio when using the "Android" perspective :(

Comment: @AjahnCharles - I prefer not to use this perspective at all (anyway - I'm always working at 'distraction free mode')... But you are right - "Android" merges everything.

Comment: This solution works well. Better than res/drawable-v2 solution. Easy to copy all to another Module or project.

Answer (score 3):

With the advent of library system, creating a library per big set of assets could be a solution.

It is still problematic as one must avoid using the same names within all the assets but using a prefix scheme per library should help with that.

It's not as simple as being able to create folders but that helps keeping things sane...

Comment: Yes, I think this is good.  If I add country flags to my drawable-ldpi etc. folders then they will get swamped.  I think that creating a library project for all generic resources will help reduce the clutter  in the project that you are actively working on.  Surprised you only have 1 upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect methods. You have to implement same way which is display [here](http://vogella.blogspot.in/2014/01/how-to-add-or-import-image-in-drawable.html).

You can also call the image under the folder through the code you can use

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable shape = res. getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_box);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewByID(R.id.textview);
tv.setBackground(shape);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not mine but I found this thread when looking for this issue, if your using Android Studio and Gradle Build system its pretty easy no plugins necessary just a little build file editing

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22426467/618419

Answer (score 1):

Gradle with Android Studio could do it this way ([link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure)).

It's in the paragraph "Configuring the Structure"

```
sourceSets {
 main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src/java'
    }
    resources {
        srcDir 'src/resources'
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a folder in main.
 like: 'res_notification_btn'

and create tree folder in. like 'drawable' or 'layout'

then in 'build.gradle' add this

```
sourceSets
            {
                main
                {
                    res
                    {
                        srcDirs = ['src/main/res_notification_btn', 'src/main/res']
                      or
                        srcDir 'src/main/res_notification_btn'
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# current dir should be drawable-hdpi/ etc

# nuke all symlinks
Dir.foreach('.') {|f|
    File.delete(f) if File.symlink?(f)
}

# symlink all resources renaming with underscores
Dir.glob("**/*.png") {|f|
    system "ln -s #{f} #{f.gsub('/', '_')}" if f.include?("/")
}
```

Comment: All this does is automate the workaround suggested by Cheezmeister. It's working for me ... care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Bash Flatten Folder script](https://github.com/nick7ikin/bash_flatten_folder) that converts folder hierarchy to a single folder

Answer (score 0):

assets/
    You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data.
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Subdirectories are not allowed, the resource must contain only [a-z0-9_.].

No you have uppercase letters, and no forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple drawable folders by having an extra folder parallel to 'res' with a subdirectory 'drawable' and then add following to gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs 'src/main/<extra_res>'
    }
}
```

Tested with gradle 6.5.1

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Xamarin (either Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms), there is a way to do this.

In the .csproj file for the Android project find the line for MonoAndroidResourcePrefix (documented, though rather poorly, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-properties)).  Add the subdirectories you are wanting to use here, separating each entry by semicolons.  When building, Visual Studio strips these prefixes so that all of the resources end up in a flat hierarchy.  You may need to reload the solution after making these changes.

[image: Example of setup in Xamarin]

These directories do not need to be subdirectories of the default Resources directory in the project.

Make sure that files you add are getting the build action set to "AndroidResource".

For Xamarin.Android, the visual editor won't recognize images and will show the error "This resource URL cannot be resolved" but the project will build and the image will be visible at runtime.

[image: Error in editor]
[image: Example in emulator]

Answer (score -6):

1. Right click on Drawable
2. Select New ---> Directory
3. Enter the directory name. Eg: logo.png(the location will already show the drawable folder by default)
4. Copy and paste the images directly into the drawable folder. While pasting you get an option to choose mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi etc for each of the images from a list. Select the appropriate option and enter the name of the image. Make sure to keep the same name as the directory name i.e logo.png
5. Do the same for the remaining images. All of them will be placed under the logo.png main folder.