# Is it possible to load a drawable from the assets folder?

Tags: android, drawable, assets

Can you load a drawable from a sub directory in the `assets` (not the drawable folder) folder?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Hope this help:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("Cloths/btn_no.png"), null);
```

Comment: Just wonder, is the file automically closed for you? For safety, I am currently give a variable the return of open(), then close it manually.

Comment: @DatVM no it doesn't automatically close the inputstream. I have created a class with static method to get the drawable from assets and added it as separate answer down below.

Comment: @СергейГрушин for vector drawable please use 
VectorDrawableCompat.createFromStream(context.assets.open("Cloths/btn_no.xml"), null)

Answer (score 8):

I recommend to use this

```
 Drawable.createFromResourceStream(resources,new TypedValue(), resources.getAssets().open(filename), null)
```

which returns properly scaled drawable thanks to resources ...

Answer (score 7):

Here's a class with static method to get the drawable from the assets. It also closes the inputstream.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by bartburg on 4-11-2015.
 */
public class AssetsReader {

    public static Drawable getDrawableFromAssets(Context context, String url){
        Drawable drawable = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = context.getAssets().open(url);
            drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can create a `Drawable` object from an `InputStream` using the [createFromStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: is it possible for drawables in drawable folder also?if yes than how?

Comment: @chiragshah I don't understand. Images in the drawable directory are converted by the system for you.

Comment: I need a quick way to load images from the assets folder as i have a lot of map tiles with same names but different directories.

Comment: @Octavien :see this que.:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885469/dynamically-show-images-from-resource-drawable

Answer (score 2):

Here is function that does this for you.

Check the returned Drawable variable for null as null may return if the path is invalid or there is an IOException.

```
public static Drawable getDrawableFromAssetFolder(String fullPath, Activity ctx) {
    Drawable d =null;
    try {
        d = Drawable.createFromStream(ctx.getAssets().open(fullPath), null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working in a RecyclerView adapter and found that **David's** answer was not working for me, (for some reason `asset.open` remained Unresolved no matter what I imported )

so I found this to work for me (Kotlin code)

```
val d = Drawable.createFromStream(context?.assets?.open("imageData/${imageName}.png"), null)
```

here is my directory, as you can see the assets start from the assets folder and here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio) on how to create that assets folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This helped getting the right density

```
private Drawable drawableFromAssetFilename(String filename) {
    AssetManager assetManager = mApplicationContext.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(mApplicationContext.getResources(), bitmap);
    return drawable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin Function to Get Drawable from Assets

Thanks to @Bart Burg

I've adapted a Java function to Kotlin for retrieving a `Drawable` from the assets folder. The Kotlin version utilizes the language's standard library functions for efficient and safe resource management. Here's the Kotlin implementation:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import java.io.IOException

object AssetsReader {

    /**
     * Gets a Drawable from the assets folder.
     * 
     * @param context The context of the application.
     * @param url The path of the drawable in the assets folder.
     * @return Drawable The drawable from the specified path, or null if an error occurs.
     */
    fun getDrawableFromAssets(context: Context, url: String): Drawable? {
        return try {
            // Automatically closes the InputStream after the operation is done
            context.assets.open(url).use { inputStream ->
                // Create a Drawable from the InputStream
                Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Log the exception and return null if an error occurs
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

At this version you can't, if you make a sub folder within your drawable folder you can't use it in your xml file, it won't be recognized when you use android:src.

Take a look at this thread: [Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

Comment: That being the case, what is the easiest way to load a couple of hundred custom map tiles to display on the screen?

Comment: Ah my question is about the assets folder, not the drawable. Question edited.

Comment: This answer is outdated now that the question has been updated.