# Changing image in imageview dynamically

Tags: android

I have a "detailed" view of some products and when the user taps one of the rows in the listview a detailed view of the product is showed. How do I change the image in the imageview when I have the name of the image file which is in the Drawable folder?

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell what's your problem. You cant't find a proper control's method or can't transform file name to name of field in R file?

Comment: I want to get a resource(image) in the drawable folder from a filename(string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using assets is more suitable solution for you? This topic was already [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884882/is-it-possible-to-load-a-drawable-from-the-assets-folder).
Otherwise you can use reflection to find a needed field in R class.