# Android setImageUri not working with asset Uri

Tags: android, image, uri

I am using the following code to set an image from the assets folder.

```
Uri numBgUri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/background_numbers.png");
numBgImage.setImageURI(numBgUri);
```

The background_numbers.png file definitely exists in the assets root directory.  I am getting a FileNotFoundException in the log: -

```
09-23 17:05:23.803: WARN/ImageView(23713): Unable to open content: file:///android_asset/background_numbers.png
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get a viable workaround for this using my own custom ContentProvider (It's easier than you think!).  Thanks to [skink on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/qj6lWmt02SU) for the tip

This code should work, you just need to set a provider URL and register it as a provider in the manifest file

```
package sirocco.widgets;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;

public class AssetContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private AssetManager mAssetManager;
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = 
            Uri.parse("content://your.provider.name");

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mAssetManager = getContext().getAssets();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String path = uri.getPath().substring(1);
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = mAssetManager.openFd(path);
            return afd;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("No asset found: " + uri);
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this helps any googlers out there with the same problem!

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for this! I didn't realize until the second time I took a good look at it that I could simply use a Uri like "content://<my_authority>/<relative_path_to_asset>" in conjunction with your solution. Straightforward solution to a problem that shouldn't exist IMO. :-|

Answer (score 0):

You need to place all images in you resources directory. For example :

```
/root/res/drawable/background_numbers.png
```

And you can access it via:

```
numBgImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_numbers);
```

Comment: Yep, I know that's a possibility, but it should also be possible to place them in the assets directory.  When releasing a new version then the resource ids don't change.

Comment: All resource ids are changed when you recompile the application, this is a normality. You can reference the specific ids using the R class so that even though the values change it will not impact anything.

Comment: Yep, I am aware of how it works.  It only changes value if you add or delete resources.  I am data driving a number of skins for my widgets.  I am using URIs, so uris to resources aren't "permanent", but assets should be. I store the uris in the sharedprefs for each widget

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to double check that:

- ImageView activity that appears in your logcat belongs to the same apk that your code. asset  files are only readable from within your application.
- The assets folder is in the project directory root.

**EDIT**

It seems that it is not possible to feed an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) directly from an asset ressource. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531989/android-setimageuri-not-working-with-asset-uri/7533725#comment-9128579) for illustration. 
As a workaround you should try to create a drawable from your asset file, then associate it with your Image view using [ImageView.setImageDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29):

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("background_numbers.png"), null);
if (null != d) numBgImage.setImageDrawable(d);
```

The first line of this code is an adaptation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884882/is-it-possible-to-load-a-drawable-from-the-assets-folder/5082672#5082672) from @IgorKhomenko .

Comment: Thanks.  I checked the log and it's definitely an error from my application.  I unzipped my APK to double check it was in the correct place, but /assets/background_numbers.png is there.  I am successfully loading a font and some properties files from assets, it's just the URI thing that isn't working for some reason.

Comment: @Ash McConnell, could you please detail numBgImage type and provide additional code?

Comment: numBgImage is an ImageView.  Here is how I get it: -  ImageView numBgImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.numBackground);

Comment: Hehe, you referenced this question ;).  Unfortunately I can't do this as it's a Widget, There are problems using Drawables / Bitmaps (if there are quite a few)

Comment: @AshMcConnell  Oh, it's a widget now? I surrender :) I think you should edit your question for completness in order to help future helpers helping you.

Comment: Hehe, well it's the configuration for a widget, but the widget uses URIs to set ImageViews (as I'm skinning).  I don't see why setImageUri shouldn't work, but that's Android for you ;)