# Import directory of images to the drawable resources in Android Studio

Tags: android, import, intellij-idea, android-studio, drawable

I want to import some icons, which are located in different directories. I know that Android Studio allows import `*.png` files directly into `drawable-*` directory of a project, but is it possible to import a directory with pictures and access them through the `@drawable/`?

Comment: can't you just use the standard copy/paste ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use subfolders in drawable:

[Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

Do you have to access the files using "R" for some reason? If not this might help:

[Is it possible to load a drawable from the assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884882/is-it-possible-to-load-a-drawable-from-the-assets-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use @Drawable/icon.pgn (name of picture with extension). You can also use any picture [format](http://vogella.blogspot.in/2014/01/how-to-call-image-id-from-drawable.html) . before that you have to import picture [correct methods](http://vogella.blogspot.in/2014/01/how-to-call-image-id-from-drawable.html).