# Is there a way to organise the res folder in android?

Tags: android

I have a lot of files in /res/raw. Is there some way to organise this folder? Simply arranging into directories makes them invisible to R.raw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sub-directories are not allowed within the Android resource folders. It is certainly inconvenient.

Previously discussed: [Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

Comment: That's a pretty conclusive answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Assets

Especially if you don't need a reference in your R class, (and no internationalization) use the **assets folder**.

```
InputStream inStream = getAssets().open("subfolder/filename.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
```

It is meant to be on the same level as your `res`/`java` folder: `src/main/assets/`

Since you asked for the `raw` folder, there is a good chance this is what you want to use anyways.