# How to create a new folder inside the drawable folder and reference an image from it?

Tags: android

I am working on an ANDROID project where  I have a lot of images and I want to organize it.
So I need to create folder inside the drawable folder.
But I don't know how to reference it in my program.

For eg: I have an image named "image.png" and I want to place it in drawable/myicons/image.png
or anywhere inside the res folder.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This is duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

You can not create folder inside drawable

the resources mechanism doesn't support subfolders in the drawable directory

However you can use the assets folder and have sub directories in there and load images that way.