# Access xml resources in subfolders in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Is it possible to have nested `value` resources?
I want to categorise my `strings` based on the Activity in which they are being displayed.
So say I would like somthing of this sort:

```
 value
  > login
   .. strings.xml
  >registration
   .. strings.xml
```

Is this possible?
If yes, how do I access these resources from the `layout` files?

Comment: Already asked before, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders/4930521#4930521

Comment: I had gone through that post, I was just wondering if it would be different in the case of `values`

Comment: Same story for other resources folders: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories/1078988#1078988 -> "No, the resources mechanism doesn't support subfolders in the drawable directory, so yes - you need to keep that hierarchy flat."

Comment: What about a "great comment" for me? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Best you can do is a naming convention.