# New folder in res in android

Tags: android, directory, android-resources

I added new folder named drawableb in res in android and put some xml in it, but when I tried to use that xml from layout, I was not able to use the folder named drawableb. Can anyone please help me how to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio and Gradle you can now have multiple [resource folders that get merged](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging). Try using multiple subfolders in your drawable folder and update the sourceSets in your build.grade file. See these answers for more details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22426467/3681880
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176029/3681880
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19859379/3681880