# android resources not found after moving

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating an Android keyboard with Eclipse. I want to implement popup keyboards which show up when you long press a key.

Therefore I assigned the

```
android:popupKeyboard="@xml/a_popup"
```

property to the key-tag and created a popup keyboard under "res/xml/a_popup.xml"

That works fine, but since I want a lot of different popup keyboards and I don't want them all to be directly in "res/xml/", so I moved the "a_popup.xml" file to "res/xml/popup_keyboards/"

But now I can't make a reference to the xml-file any more from my popupKeyboard-property by saying

```
android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboards/a_popup"
```

If I do so, I get the message, that there is no resource which matches the given name. There is also no entry in the R.java file, although I cleaned the project.

I also tried to reference the popup keyboard by an ID but then I get a ResourcesNotFound Exception everytime I longpress the button.

Has anybody an idea why this happens?

Comment: does eclipse show you errors in the error view?

Comment: I only get the the error in my code which says "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'popupKeyboard' with value '@xml/popup_keyboards/a_popup')." and I can't build my project.

Comment: The resource file can not have subdirectories.  [See this question.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories

Comment: ok thanks, now at least I know why it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use nested lists in resources in Android. "res/xml/popup_keyboards/" - it's wrong, you can't create directories under xml dir, only files.

Comment: ok, if that isn't possible I would try to reference the keyboards by their IDs. Then I could pack mulitple keyboard layouts in one xml file. But unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Why you don't do like this: "res/xml/a_popup.xml", "res/xml/a_popup2.xml", "res/xml/a_popup3.xml"   ?

Comment: I need popups for about 20 keys of my keyboard. That would spam the res/xml/ folder pretty much.

Comment: It's OK, there isn't other solution.

Comment: ok thank you, I has to work for now but I will change that later on