# Organize Contents of drawable-hdpi (mdpi, ldpi, etc.) via folders

Tags: android, resources, drawable, organization

My android project uses many images, and I have images for different DPIs as well. Currently, all the images reside in their respective folders in project, i.e. `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi` and so on.

It works, but is it possible to have them organized in folders within their `drawable` folder? like:

```
drawable-hdpi
    > common
    > activity1
    > activity2


drawable-mdpi
    > common
    > activity1
    > activity2
```

And, I could access them as, `R.drawable.common.image1`, `R.drawable.activity2.icon1`, and so on.

Comment: You can do this only with Gradle

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19859379

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the resources mechanism doesn't support subfolders in the drawable directory, so - you need to keep that hierarchy flat.

[Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

As of Android 2.2, this doesn't cause a compiler error, but any subdirectories are ignored when generating the R class. This really sucks, and makes it hard to manage larger projects.

Comment: My Sad :-( Also, didn't knew the question already has been asked. Thanks anyways.