# Sub folders in drawable resource folder?

Tags: android, drawable, android-resources, subdirectory

I would like to create sub folders in drawable folder. I have a lot of file(such as png, xml) in drawable folder. I want to create sub folders in there to find the files easily. Can I create sub folders like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

This is now (sort of) possible by using Android Studio and Gradle.

Whilst subfolders are still not possible, it is possible to separate resources into different sets and have them [merged by the build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging).

As an example, to simplify my project, I wanted to keep theme specific drawables separate from standard drawables.

I created a new resource folder named 'res_lighttheme' as illustrated in the picture below.

[image: Folder Structure]

I then added a pointer to this folder to my build.gradle file like this. To add more than one just add another line to the definition.

[image: Build Gradle]

The result is that BOTH folders are then considered to be valid destinations for resources. A build error will be generated if there is a conflict. i.e if the same resource is included in both folders.

Comment: I get the following error in my theme files: `URI is not registered`. The line in question is always: `<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Could you comment on the issue that @letiagoalves brought up?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with @letiagoalves

Comment: facing same issue made a folder in layout folder and shifted the previous layouts in that folder after that getting error

Comment: This error will occur if you create subfolders in your *existing* resource folders. Each folder referenced must be ONE folder with NO subfolders. e.g 'src/main/res2' and 'src/main/res' are fine.  'src/main/res/res2' and 'src/main/res' are not