# URI is not registered in resource file

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using **Android Studio and Gradle** to develop an Android application.

I am creating a theme and I got dozen of resource files. So to make my project cleaner I [(following this SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19859379/1873446) **moved all theme related files to another folder called `res_theme`** and inside my **build.gradle file** I added the following to merge the two resource files folders:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res {
            srcDir 'src/main/res_theme'
        }
    }
}
```

Now **when I build my project** I get the following **error in several resource files**:

```
URI is not registered in resource file
```

That error occurs in this line:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Another thing I noticed is this popup message:

```
'main' in build cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'
```

in this line: `main {`

### EDIT

**Project structure:**

```
AppName
|--------lib
|--------src
         |--------main
                  |--------java
                  |--------res
                  |--------res_theme
                  |--------AndroidManifest.xml
|--------AppName.iml
|--------build.gradle
|--------proguard-rules.txt
```

If you need more detail please tell me

Comment: sourceSets block is obviously inside android block

Comment: I think the directory name should be res-theme instead of res_theme.

Comment: underscore is not accepted in folder names? here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19859379/1873446 he used `res_lighttheme`. I can't try it now but I will try later

Comment: Let me know the file name in which the error is coming, File where you have written `<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` .

Comment: @pyus13 every resource file inside `res_theme` folder with that line in the definition. for example the main theme file: **themes_appname.xml**

Comment: are you putting xml file in directory like res_layout/values/themes_appname.xml ? if not try this.

Comment: @pyus13 yes, more exactly `res_theme/values/themes_appname.xml`, `res_theme/values/styles_appname.xml`, `res_theme/drawable/appnametheme_edit_text_holo_light.xml` and so on....

Answer (score 0):

That `sourceSets` block needs to be inside your `android` block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible.

I've tried next lines:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 9
       targetSdkVersion 16

       versionCode 4
       versionName "1.0.0.6"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDirs = ["src/main/res", "src/main/res2"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I added simple string to `res2` folder:

```
<resources>
    <string name="test1">Test 1</string>
</resources>
```

And when I simply try to access this string:

```
setTitle( R.string.test1 );
```

I got compilation error - can not find symbol variable `test1`.

You can try to fix this with flavours but I don't think this is right usage of flavours. You can also make library inly for theme but again I don't think this is optimal solution.

Comment: first of all thanks for the attention. I am stuck and I can't find any help. why this `instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')`?

Comment: also looking at this SO answer it seems it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577782/sub-folders-in-drawable-resource-folder/19859379#19859379

Comment: I removed confusing line. And maybe it was but not anymore with new version. I would be much confident about when I will see code of android gradle plugin:)

Comment: Have you seen this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging ? It really seems it is possible to merge 2 resource folders