# Sub folders in res/drawable folder. Uri not registered error

Tags: android, xml

Once again this question. I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577782/sub-folders-in-drawable-resource-folder/19859379#19859379), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories/32008213?noredirect=1#comment56219612_32008213) and other related threads. But after following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19859379/4656400) answer I don't know how to deal with following error: 'URI is not registered' for `<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` lines in .xml files that i'd like to store in res/drawables/my-sub-folder. Is there any solution for that or it's just still impossible?

Comment: It's not possible... =(

Comment: is it still not possible , any answers?

Answer (score -1):

To remove the error in your sub-directory defined in `sourceSets` 'src/main/res/yourdirectorysystem' you need to ad a folder labeled `layout` just like in the res folder.

example

```
res-
    layout-
           horizontal- (defined as 'src/main/res/layout/horizontal')
                      layout-
                             somefile.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to enter it like that but it came out as one line. I'm not sure what I did wrong as it was my first post here.