# Android an drawable folder

Tags: java, android

I have a bunch of subfolders and I want to put them in the drawable folder so that I can support all screens is there another way I can do it because I read that you cant put subfolder but I want to support all screens

Comment: why do you need those to support all screens. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Just make a regular drawable folder in your res/ folder.

Comment: Im going to have 9 folders and my Idea was to put on drawable-hdpi it folders with its images and 9 folders for drawable-ldpi  etc.  In my code I have it where depending on the number you get it will load you the images

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but as you seem to know about the different drawable folders, the answer is simply that you can't have subfolders in drawable folders and you should probably name the files accordingly instead of adding subfolders (a_imagex, b_imagex...) to achieve whatever it is you try to achieve...?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need subfolders in the drawable folder but different drawable-folders. 
Such as:

drawable-hdpi

drawable-xhdpi

drawable-mdpi

and have a look at the documentation in @Raghunandan's comment!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories) which says

No, the resources mechanism doesn't support subfolders in the drawable directory, so yes - you need to keep that hierarchy flat.

From my own experiments it seems that having a subfolder with any items in it, within the res/drawable folder, will cause the resource compiler to fail -- preventing the R.java file from being generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No sub-folders is required at all for supporting in all screen sizes. Just put your data's (images, icons etc.) on the default drawable folders [drwable-hdpi,drwable-ldpi,drwable-mdpi.. ].And don't forget to keep required sizes of the images,icons for different screens. For more details please follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `drawable` folder to support al screens.
Create one if it doesn't exist.