# Populating image switcher dynamically android

Tags: android, android-drawable, imageswitcher

How can I populate the image switcher dynamically, when I have the images in the drawable folder and sub folder .. like drawable-ldpi/S_001/a001_001.jpg.

I have tried to populate one image, but the application crashed.
Here is the code:

```
ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("S_001/a001_001.jpg", "drawable", getPackageName())));
```

I need some assisstance.

Comment: it is not good to make the new folder in the drawable folder.

Comment: so U are saying that I copy all image files in the drawable foler. so how can I take all of there ids at once in an array?

Comment: When I run the application this error comes "Unfortunately, application1 has stopped."

Answer (score 1):

`drawables` folder is for img resources used by your app, like icons, 9-patches, backgrounds and other ui elements. [You can't put subdirectories there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

If you plan to use some photos in an ImageSwitcher or anything like this, you should use `assets` folder. [Read this to find out more.](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationProjects)