# Way to organize drawables?

Tags: android, image, drawable

I read on [Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories) that you cannot make sub directories in the drawable folder. Is there another way to organize your drawables so you can access them with R.something? I tried assets but I couldnt access that in java code?

Comment: No ther is no other way to manage them. You can not organize the images like in iphone devs.

You have to put your images in HDPI MDPI LDPI folders...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if you want to access them by R.id.xxx.  They need to be in the drawable folder without subfolders.  If you put them in assets you can read them in, but they you're responsible for building Bitmap objects out of them, not the Android framework.