# Create another res subfolder to layout files

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I wanna organise my code with subfolder into res folder for layout.

**I know we cannot create subfolder into layout folder but i can create subfolder into res folder.**

Now how can i SetContentView with my new folder.

-res/

---subfolder1_layout

-----sub1_layout.xml

---layout

-----layout.xml

And setcontentView (getClass().getResources("/res/subfolder1_layout/sub1_layout.xml"));
does not work.

How can i do that please ?

Comment: This question was asked already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4930521/1970317

Comment: You cannot do that. [Refer answer by Reto Meier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1078988/1008278)

Comment: From the sounds of it, you're better off reading this as well: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.

[Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders?rq=1)

Comment: I don't want to do that. I want to create subfolder into RES directory and use it to setcontentview

Comment: You don't want, but you'll have to. What you want is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible directly.

Consider using a common name prefix for layouts belonging together so they sort together.

With the support of build tooling such as Gradle you can get have multiple resource folders in your project. Read more about [resource merging](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging).