# Xamarin Local Images from Resources

Tags: c#, android, resources, xamarin

I am having a trouble in Xamarin. I added a folder in ***drawable***. I named it "**puzzles**". Now, I can not set source of the **ImageView** which image is in that folder. I cant see my files which is in puzzles folder. Here is screenshot.

[image]

Comment: "Why is it called puzzles?! That's the puzzle" - Sry :D you can't create subfolders in resources. Maybe check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1078988/3067372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are not allowed to have sub folders in the `Resources` folders. If you need a visible difference between your files in the `drawable` directory go for a naming convention like calling them `puzzles_nameOfFile`

Comment: It is so interesting. Files may be mixed. I just would like to seperate them. Thank you for your reply.