# Adapter display png from resources doesn't work

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner, android-resources

I'm trying to display a png inside a custom spinner through its adapter.

This spinner contains different countries at the moment it displays:

> countryName - codePhone

But I would like to add a flag to get this:

> flag.png - countryName - codePhone

So I have created in drawable a folder which contains all my png flags: drawable/flags/..."

Here my adapter:

> public class SpinnerCountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
>
> ```
> private Context context;
>
> private LayoutInflater inflater;
>
> private TreeMap<String, String> countryNameDigits = new TreeMap<String, String>();
> private TreeMap<String, String> countryCodeName = new TreeMap<String, String>();
>
> private String[] keys;
>
> private CountryCodePhone ccp;
> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> public SpinnerCountryAdapter(Context context, CountryCodePhone ccp) {
>     this.ccp = ccp;
>     this.context = context;
>     this.countryNameDigits = ccp.getCountryNameDigits();
>     this.countryCodeName = ccp.getCountryCodeName();
>     this.keys = countryNameDigits.keySet().toArray(new String[ccp.getCountryNameDigits().size()]);
>
>     inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
> }
>
> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>     return countryNameDigits.size();
> }
>
> @Override
> public String getItem(int position) {
>     return countryNameDigits.get(keys[position]);
> }
>
> @Override
> public long getItemId(int position) {
>     return 0;
> }
>
> public int getPosition(String s){
>
>     int position = 0;
>
>     for (String key : countryNameDigits.keySet()) {
>
>         if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
>
>             return position;
>
>         }else{
>
>             position++;
>         }
>     }
>     return 0;
> }
>
> @Override
> public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
> }
>
> @Override
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
> }
>
> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> private View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>
>     ViewHolder holder;
>
>     if (convertView == null) {
>         holder = new ViewHolder();
>
>         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_country_spinner, null);
>
>         holder.countryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countryname);
>         holder.countryCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countrycode);
>
>         holder.imageFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countryflag);
>
>         convertView.setTag(holder);
>     } else {
>         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
>     }
>
>     String key_countryName = keys[position];
>     String value_countryCode = getItem(position).toString();
>
>     holder.countryName.setText(key_countryName);
>     holder.countryCode.setText(value_countryCode);
>
>     //TODO display correct flag - country<Name, Digits> / country<Code, Name>
>     for (TreeMap.Entry<String, String> ndItem : countryNameDigits.entrySet()) {
>         String key_name = ndItem.getKey();
>
>         for (TreeMap.Entry<String, String> cnItem : countryCodeName.entrySet()) {
>             String key_code = cnItem.getKey();
>             String value_name = cnItem.getValue().toString();
>
>             if (key_name.equalsIgnoreCase(value_name)){
>                 String flagName = key_code.toLowerCase();
>                 holder.imageFlag.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/flags/"
> ```
>
> + flagName+".png", null, context.getPackageName()));
>                   }
>
> ```
>         }
>     }
>     return convertView;
> }
>
> static class ViewHolder {
>     TextView countryName;
>     TextView countryCode;
>
>     ImageView imageFlag;
> } }
> ```

The part which doesn't work is this one (which should display a flag.png):

> for (TreeMap.Entry ndItem :
>   countryNameDigits.entrySet()) {
>               String key_name = ndItem.getKey();
>
> ```
>         for (TreeMap.Entry<String, String> cnItem : countryCodeName.entrySet()) {
>             String key_code = cnItem.getKey();
>             String value_name = cnItem.getValue().toString();
>
>             if (key_name.equalsIgnoreCase(value_name)){
>                 String flagName = key_code.toLowerCase();
>                 holder.imageFlag.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/flags/"
> ```
>
> + flagName+".png", null, context.getPackageName()));
>                   }
>
> ```
>         }
>     }
> ```

And here I'm not sure about :

> holder.imageFlag.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/flags/" + flagName+".png", null, context.getPackageName()));

This line is not null but nothing is displayed. Did I missed something ?

Comment: A working example: http://fatoumatabintou.blogspot.it/2012/02/custom-spinner-with-icon-and-text.html

Comment: There's no way to create your own drawable subfolder.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier(flagName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
holder.imageFlag.setImageResource(identifier);
```