# How to give icon path to xml in android

Tags: android, xml

I've created a directory inside drawable directory which contains two icons "empty_star.png". Now how to give address of these icons in style.xml

i tried following:

```
 <item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="drawable/icons/empty_star" />

<item android:drawable="drawable/icons/empty_star" />
```

but it shows error.

i also tried ***@drwable/icons/empty_star*** but still getting error.

Comment: try this  `drawable/empty_star`..

Comment: show your error log..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star"
```

Comment: this is alos showing error. this thing is working when i place icon inside drawbale directory. but i've created another directory inside drawble in which i've stored icons.

Comment: Android does not support subfolders in the drawable directory. You should keep all the images in the `/res/drawable` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The resources mechanism doesn't support subfolders in the drawable directory. You need to keep that hierarchy flat. Place your images in drawable folder and use it as `android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star"`

Answer (score 0):

[Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

According to the answer posted earlier, resource mechanism does not support sub folders in drawable folder. So you should maintain flat hierarchy.