# android customize drawable folder to subfolder

Tags: android, android-drawable, subdirectory

**Sub-Folder** *I didn't mean the drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi, etc
but* **@drawable\myfolder\img.png**

I'm a bit concerned on customizing the folder structure in drawable similar the way we have package to structure the java files.I'm using too many images for my project and when I try to copy activity layout xml; searching for the images in drawable, I felt it boring! Does android have such feature or some wayout?

Comment: Have you tried [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories) first?

Comment: Yes! I've looked through that question though!
I got conflicting answers max with no and some with plugins.
I wan't some core way android supports with some filthy paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, currently this way exists. I also have many drawables and layouts, so tried to start from layouts and then added drawables and menus. I recommend to see [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders/51876729#51876729) and http://alexzh.com/tutorials/how-to-store-layouts-in-different-folders-in-android-project/.

Yes, I have now new resources in new subfolders. It requires time to manage (create res folders, edit `build.gradle`), but a folder tree becomes more neat. Sometimes AS cannot find resources during compilation. In this case I have to create new folders and edit build.gradle. Probably after several weeks everything will be done.

UPDATE

It has worked until Android Studio updated to 3.2 (and 3.2.1). Currently if you move any drawable, layout, menu resource to another folder (and add this folder to `build.gradle` as written in the articles above) you cannot normally use it. Before 3.2 we could simply press `Build > Rebuild Project` and reference to that resource. Now they have broken this behaviour and you should press `File > Invalidate caches / Restart... > Just Restart` (or close and open AS) to access this drawable as usual. If you don't want to restart AS, you can use the resource, but write a path to it manually like `@drawable/reset_password`, AS won't hint as you type and won't draw it in Design tab.

If you use `Kotlin Android extensions` and reference to ids like `send_button` (without `findViewById()`) you will get so many bugs that can't imagine. If you change resources, often nothing changes in layouts until you rebuild the project. This is because Kotlin caches resources. I often forget about it and waste hours.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, NO.
There was an interesting [post](https://plus.google.com/+DmytroDanylyk/posts/bjYgPZFK1ti) on G+ with a workaround for the layout dir, that works also for the drawables dir. I guess.

All the infos are [here](http://www.dmytrodanylyk.com/android-file-grouping-plugin/)

Comment: I was just looking the last link you gave :D

Comment: @ArmasCyndromic but do you see that this plugin only shows for you in Android studio in a different way, it doesn't actually change any file locations

Comment: Absolutely, I'm searching some more detail

Answer (score -1):

Android doesn't support subfolders within its predefined directories, the only thing possible is for you to create directories within the res directory