# Failed to convert a drawable, even when using correct file naming system

Tags: android, android-studio

I am almost certain I have named all of my files appropriately, all small letters and underscores. (or well I realize now Trees and Status need to be renamed. I misspell my folder name originally, but I have spelt it right since the screenshots and the issues still apply.)
The current file I'm trying to make work is '**blank.png**'
In program images that came with android studio do work.

[When in the Project category these are the images files I have tried to import into my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8j7K.jpg)
[When under the Android category it acts like these files aren't even there, I tried pasting the folders from Project to Android within android studio, but it says they exist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2cOh.jpg)

When I change

> "android:src="drawable/bg_elements/blank.png"

to

> "android:src="drawable/bg_elements/blank"

Nothing changes.

--
When I change it to either

> "android:src="@drawable/bg_elements/blank.png"

or

> "android:src="@drawable/bg_elements/blank"

It makes it red, and when I hover over it, it gives me the message:

> '/' is not a valid resource name character Validates resource
>   reference inside Android XML files.

When I press Alt+Enter I get the Options:

> Inspection 'Android Resources Validation' options
>  Override
>   Resource in Other Configuration...
>  Inject language or reference

---

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in making these images show?
Are you not allowed to have specific folders in the drawable folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your drawable directory contains subdirectories with files, and you're trying to access them, this will be useful (res mechanism doesn't support subdirectories): [Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)