# Images management, array of images

Tags: java, android, image, drawable

I have 35 images named from `pic1.png` to `pic35.png` in my `res\drawable` folder. I need to create array of this pics to fill my ListView. I know I need some loop.

```
int[] img;
for (int i = 1; i <= 35; i++) {
            //here should be my loop body, but i dunno :( i tried this, but ofc this is wrong.
            img = R.drawable.pic[i];
        }
```

One more question:
is there any chance to manage my images in `drawable` folder? I mean, if I have two packs of images, I can't do `res\drawable\pack1` and `res\drawable\pack2` folders, is the only way to manage images to give em names like `pack1_pic1` etc?

Comment: You can get drawable by string name. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your first question:

you can set image id to your int array using:

```
int[] img;
for (int i = 1; i <= 35; i++) {
            img[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("pic"+i, "drawable", getPackageName());
        }
```

which would return the value of `R.drawable.pic1...35;`

Regarding your second question

No, the resources mechanism doesn't support subfolders in the drawable directory,

see this: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 35; i++) {
   Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier("pic"+i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
```