# Is it possible to create multiple directories for drawable in res?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2.3

So I have tried creating new directories by right clicking the res folder then on new--> Android Resource Directory.Then I changed the Resource Type to drawable.

After doing all that I copied my images into this new directory that I have created and when I try to assign them to an imageview that was not assigned yet an image through the xml with the command android:src="@mydir/mypic" android studio does not recognise my custom folder name. Is this even possible?
I am using android studio  2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create subfolders for drawables in the res/drawable folder.
See this question here in SO.

[Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

Answer (score 1):

@Aris I think it is possible to create multiple directories using gradle,

I read on mediumn about Android Project Structure - Alternative way

Please check this link,

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/android-project-structure-alternative-way-29ce766682f0

Please read Conclusion carefully.

Thanks