# Error: String types not allowed (at 'src' with value 'splash/splash1.jpg'

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview

I am developing a splash screen on Android using Xamarin. I have a picture called "splash1.jpg" placed in my various drawable subfolders which contains the subfolder "splash". Thus, for example, I have a "resources/drawable-hdpi/splash/splash1.jpg" and a "resources/drawable-mdpi/splash/splash1.jpg".

In my layout for main.axml I have a line  for the imageview source

> android:src="@drawable/splash/splash1"

And the following line is autogenerated in my resources.cs file

> public const int splash/splash1 = 2130837505;

There is an error with the slash in splash/slash1 const name which causes multiple errors on compilation.

How should I refer to my file in drawables when it is in a subdirectory in the drawable folders?

Thanks.

Comment: can you mark my answer as correct please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android *don't* support subfolders inside `/drawable` folders.
Please remove your `/splash` folder and place the `splash` images inside `/drawable` folder directly.

get more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories).

Comment: That's nailed it down. Jzeferino. I read somewhere on the Internet that you can organize your resources in drawables subfolders, must be one of those things you can't believe all you read on the Internet. 

Thanks for your answer anyway. Appreciate it.