# How to add many folders of photos to my project and read them?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I know how to add photos to drawable folder and read them from it .. but in my case  I have many folders each of them contains photos ..

so, how to add all the folders to my project in android studio

folder1
folder2
folder3
..

and how to read get photos from them, for example: in drawable we use : R.drawable.photo1

so, how to do that in my case ..

and thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't completely understand your question, you can create folders under /res/ folder from there you can access them by using R.foldername.photoname

Comment: when I copy the folder and  paste it in  /res .. the folder added to /res .. but  it doesn't show up  in android studio ..and when I want read from it  he didn't find the forlder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

Comment: @Dev I guess you passed it from the outside, if so just refresh the res folder or reset android studio then you will have access to it

Comment: @AntonMakov Sadly, it doesn't work

Comment: Try to close the project and reopen it if it's still doesn't work. Try to create a new project and create the hierarcy that I told you before