# Android sub-directory inside res/drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I'm creating an android project which is closely related to poker game but an offline one in this I've to add all 52 cards in the res/drawable folder which is becoming quite messy with all other images and xmls.

For Example

```
res/drawable
Spade
spade_ace.png
spade_two.png
Hearts
hearts_ace.png
hearts_two.png
```

I did refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories) but I couldn't find any suitable solution, is there any way i can organise this by creating sub-directories or is there any other way possible

Comment: You cam make this hierarchy in assets folder with image name and display accordingly But all image are save in drawable folder

Comment: Try assests instead of drawable

Comment: by referring from the link i did try storing it in assets dir but it's still not proper and it's becoming quite tedious to call all cards in .class files