# How to access images from asset in drawable xml

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-assets

Since it is not possible to create sub folders in a Drawable folder, I want to move the images to an asset folder, and divide the images into different folders.

My question, how do I access the image in the asset folder from the XML in the Drawable folder?

[image: es f]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access assets images from the xml file. Assets files are available only via [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).
You should decide if you want more to have images in subfolders in assets and load files programmatically (it's not hard) or set images in xml.
Edit: I've found the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077357/8097941) , you can check some methods.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Assets folder you can specify additional resource folders in your app gradle ie:

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
             resources{
                 main.res.srcDirs+= "src/main/button_res"
             }
        }
    }
```