# How to properly organize the resources in the res folder?

Tags: android, resources

I created a project in android studio using Kotlin

I try now to organise my files in the "**res**" area.
in **drawable**, there is a lot of **png** files ( icons used in my app ), 
and a lot of custom controls: `xml` files, using shape, solid, stoke...

when I try to create a new resource directory, using "resource type" = drawable :
it does not compile : "shape" "solid", etc... are not recognized anymore during compilation.
android studio require me to put ALL my shape in drawable folder, which start to be a big mess.

how can I add several folder in res area.
I want to separate properly the icons, the `xml` files in separate folder ?

thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Android don't let you do that, all drawables must be in the drawable folder - and we can't create subdirectories ([Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)).

In order to be able to manage all this mess, I recommend prepending the drawable type to the name, so you have:

```
icon_my_icon_name
shape_my_shape_name
solid_my_solid_name
...
```