# Any way to insert sub-directories in Drawable? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I found that back in 2009, it was impossible to insert sub-directories for the Drawable folder ([Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)).

Since it has been more than ten years from then, I wonder if Android Studio ever updated a way to insert sub-directories to group images together. I added more than 80 images in the Drawable folder, and it's pretty bugging me...
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, the Android resources mechanism doesn't support any custom directory or subdirectory yet (instead of the assets for example).

**However**, you can implement a structure similar to:

```
|--- res
|
|--- circles
|       |--- drawable
|               |--- my-circle.xml
|
|--- triangles
|       |--- drawable
|               |--- my-triangle.xml
|
|--- selectors
        |--- drawable
                |--- my-selector.xml
```

And with Gradle you can add `src/main/circles`, `src/main/triangles` and `src/main/selectors` to your `res` directories.

**e.g.**

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs += ['src/main/circles', 'src/main/triangles', 'src/main/selectors']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply! You saved my thousands of scrolling to find the exact name of a file name.

Comment: Antoniolli Just did! I am new to here and didn't know about the feature. Thanks again!

Comment: Note that you can't have two files with same filename, even if they are in distinct subdirectories.