# Adding a folder of images to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently working on a learning project for toddlers where I am currently styling the layouts. I am trying to locate the folders where the images of the numbers and letters are kept and I copied them to drawables but when I click on the `ImageView` I am unable to find these pictures. Is there a way in which I could access these photos and use them in the other style layouts. The folder images contain the number of images and the folder alphabet contains the letter of images. These can be seen when I reveal drawable in the finder but not in the Project tool window under drawables. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlxFB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make any subFolder inside the drawable folder, Android Studio ignores any nested folders and will show you only images inside the drawable folder.

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078988/5745574) for more details.